# QSqlDatabase Connect to a SQL Server Compact Edition database

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, qt, visual-c++

I'm trying to connect to my database file (*.sdf) from my Qt application.
How my connection string should look like?
I'm thinking at something like:

```
"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQL Server Compact Edition;DATABASE=C:\\myDb.sdf"
```